# Using join() on a nested tuple populated from an Excel range

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pycharm, tuples

I have a nested tuple named `rng` that was created from an Excel worksheet:

```
from win32com.client import GetObject

exl = GetObject(None, "Excel.Application")
exl_wbs = exl.Workbooks
wb_names = [wb.Name for wb in exl_wbs]
sht = exl_wbs[1].Sheets(2)

lrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
lcol = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(1).Column
rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(lrow, lcol))
```

Output with `print(rng)`:

```
((2.0, 'I', None, 'AMC'), (2.0, 'I', None, 'DC-01'), (3.0, 'I', None, 'GC-01') #etc..
```

I am attempting to break up this tuple in separate lines, as follows

```
(2.0, 'I', None, 'AMC')
(2.0, 'I', None, 'DC-01')
(3.0, 'I', None, 'GC-01')
```

I have attempted use `print("\n".join(map(str, rng)))`, but this puts every item in a new line:

```
2.0
I
None
AMC
2.0
I
None
DC-01
3.0
I
None
GC-01
```

How do I go about breaking up the tuple so it is structured conform my needs?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. When I run your code, I get exactly what you say you want.

Comment: @glibdud I was about to comment I had already tried below methods but decided to test the code regardless. As it works fine, but not for my initial variable, I suspect the tuple populated by a worksheet's range behaves differently..

Comment: you already did it. i check your code, it gives what you expect

Comment: I have updated my question with the code that populated the `rng` variable. Hopefully that sheds some light on the issue

Comment: @TimStack what is the output of `repr(rng)`?

Comment: Can't you just print every item of you tuple, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex no output whatsoever

Comment: @MLAlex but that's not what I want, is it?

Comment: That's very strange, if you just try iterating the tuple what do you see? eg `for r in rng: print(r, type(r), len(r))` ?

Comment: I wasn't aware `repr` needs to be executed in the python console. It ouputs `'<COMObject Range>'` @Alex

Comment: @Alex that outputs `2.0 <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'> 1` etc all in new lines

Comment: So, it's not a tuple. I have no idea how to change it to one. I can't find up to date docs, but you could try opening an issue https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering my own question for future reference*

As [Alex rightfully commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574044/using-join-on-a-nested-tuple-populated-from-an-excel-range#comment101609910_57574044), the `Range` object is not a tuple. As this object is a direct active link to the cells in the Excel worksheet, attempting to alter the object also alters the worksheet.

I ended up looping through the rows in the worksheet instead. I could then loop through this iteration's range and add the range's values to a list. This list is no longer linked to Excel, so changes can be made easily. I had to get rid of the 'None' (empty cell) and decimal values which you can see in the code below.

```
for i in range(2, lrow + 1):
    newrng = []
    rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(i, 1), sht.Cells(i, lcol))
    for c in rng:
        try:
            float(str(c))
            newrng.append(int(c))
        except ValueError:
            if str(c) == 'None':
                newrng.append('')
            else:
                newrng.append(str(c))
```